# Create a log of all changes in worksheet , including copy and pasting values to a range

Tags: excel, vba

The attached code works great for single entry changes to sheet1 , saved to a Log Sheet on sheet9. But I need to also find a way to log all changes if there is a copy and paste of values to a range. So each cell changed in the copy and paste is recorded.

```
Dim vOldVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim bBold As Boolean
Dim col
Dim row

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With
If IsEmpty(vOldVal) Then vOldVal = "Empty Cell"
bBold = Target.HasFormula
With Sheet9

With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1)
.Value = vOldVal

row = Target.row
col = Target.Column
.Offset(0, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(row, 1).Value 'id
.Offset(0, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(row, 2).Value 'name
.Offset(0, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(1, col).Value 'column name
With .Offset(0, 1)
If bBold = True Then
.ClearComments
.AddComment.Text Text:= _
"Dev:" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & _
"Bold values are the results of formulas"
End If
.Value = Target
.Font.Bold = bBold
End With
.Offset(0, 2) = Date & " " & Time

End With
.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End With
vOldVal = vbNullString
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Sheet10.PivotTables("Log_Pivot").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

vOldVal = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: Please can you read up on indenting code as it will make your code much more readable and easier to spot errors. Perhaps you could turn `vOldVal` into a range or array and loop through it in your Change event.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response , is it possible to see how saving this date to an array could work , as I have not worked with arrays before

Comment: Actually a bit more complicated than I first thought as if you paste multiple cells the target will only pick up the first.